# procmail and libnotify: how to display emails received?

Tags: email, notifications, procmail, libnotify

I am trying to get `procmail` to work with `libnotify` (`notify-send`). My `.procmailrc` has a couple of recipes, which just essentially filter mails into different folders.. nothing fancy.

Most of my recipes are like:

```
:0:
* ^TO_*(address)
FOLDER/
```

I add the following to my `.procmailrc`, *after* all the rules. I copied this recipe from Google. What I want is that on every new mail (before or after processing my other recipes), `notify-send` command below is run.

```
:0 ic:
| DISPLAY=:0.0 notify-send "New mail!"
```

But This doesn't work. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Do you get any error messages in your procmail log?

Comment: @larsks: I got it working by setting Xauthority path. However, I still don't know if my rule is OK or not.

Comment: You need to make your notification rule the first `procmail` rule in your setup. As it stands, your email is consumed by whatever rule matches it first, so it never gets to the notification rule; having the notification rule first, with a `c` flag (carbon copy), ensures your email will cause a notification and will still be processed by the following rules.